# Play sounds quickly

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio, playback

I'm making a javascript code where if you press a button, there's a sound.

HTML piece of code:

```
<audio id="sound" src="sound.wav"></audio>
...
<input class="button_white" type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('sound').play()"></input>
```

I noticed that when I press quickly the button, it doesn't play any sound (a sort of lag).
Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="sound.wav" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

use built in "control" attribute to play the source file.

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio  or
2. Button tag to handle it

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
    x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    x.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="sound.wav">
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>
```

Comment: I've readen your code (thanks for the timely reply) , but it isn't the thing I want to do. I need to press the button to play a 1 second sound (entirely). If I choose to press the button quickly (for example every second or half second), I often can't hear the sound.

Comment: Are you trying to create a toggle button which plays ans pause the audio with single button?

Comment: Not exactly. The button doesn't have to pause the audio. It only play a one second sound. During or after the sound, I can press again the button and the sound can start overlapping the previously sound. I want to use this to make an acoustic keyboard.